# JAXB unmarshal list to map adapter

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no' ?>
<Result>
    <Module name="module">
        <TestCase name="testCase1"></TestCase>
        <TestCase name="testCase2"></TestCase>
        <TestCase name="testCase3"></TestCase>
    </Module>
</Result>
```

I want to convert the **List** of TestCase to **HashMap**.

**Result.java**

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "Result")
public class Result {

    @XmlElement(name = "Module")
    private List<Module> modules;
}
```

**Module.java**

```java
public class Module {

    @XmlAttribute
    public String name;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TestCaseAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name = "TestCase")
    private Map<String, TestCase> testCases;

}
```

**TestCase.java**

```java
public class TestCase {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;
}
```

**TestCaseAdapter.java**

```java
public class TestCaseAdapter extends XmlAdapter<List<TestCase>, Map<String, TestCase>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, TestCase> unmarshal(List<TestCase> testCases) throws Exception {
        Map<String, TestCase> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (TestCase testCase : testCases) {
            map.put(testCase.getName(), testCase);
        }
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public List<TestCase> marshal(Map<String, TestCase> testCaseMap) throws Exception {
        return new ArrayList<>(testCaseMap.values());
    }
}
```

However, the above code does not work well. When the code is executed, the following **error** occurs.

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

java.util.List is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.util.List
        at private java.util.Map com.nebula.parser.model.Module.testCases
        at com.nebula.parser.model.Module
        at private java.util.List com.nebula.parser.model.Result.modules
        at com.nebula.parser.model.Result
```

So I changed the code as below and it worked well. but **TestCase[] is empty**.

```java
public class TestCaseAdapter extends XmlAdapter<TestCase[], Map<String, TestCase>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, TestCase> unmarshal(TestCase[] testCases) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public TestCase[] marshal(Map<String, TestCase> testCaseMap) throws Exception {
        return new TestCase[0];
    }
}
```

I want to solve this problem, but I can't figure it out. I will be thankful if you help me.

Comment: use ArrayList instead of List in TestCaseAdapter.java

Comment: @Lakshan Even if it is used as ArrayList, it becomes Empty as it is used as Array.